# Order of orthant probabilities in a prolate multinormal distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian, geometric-probability

This is inspired by the negative answer to the conjecture in [Which orthant probabilities are the largest? (For a multivariate normal distribution)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356787/which-orthant-probabilities-are-the-largest-for-a-multivariate-normal-distribu).

Suppose $X$ has the $k$-dimensional multivariate normal distribution $N(0, \Sigma)$, where $k \ge 2$ and $\Sigma$ has two distinct eigenvalues: the larger is $\lambda > 1$ and single, and the smaller is $1$ and $(k-1)$-fold. A practical interpretation is that we take the $k$-dimensional standard normal distribution, stretch it $\sqrt{\lambda}$-fold in one direction, and rotate arbitrarily. So the distribution is "prolate in one direction". Let $u$ be the eigenvector associated to the larger eigenvalue.

Number the $2^k$ orthants $i=1,\ldots,2^k$ in some convenient order, and let $e_i = (e_{i1},\ldots,e_{ik}) = (\pm 1, \ldots, \pm 1)/\sqrt{k}$ be the unit vector pointing to the "center" of the $i$th orthant.  Let $p_i = \mathbb{P} (\forall j=1,\ldots,k: \; X_j e_{ij} > 0)$ be the probability that $X$ is in the $i$th orthant.

**Question.** Are the orthant probabilities $p_i$ in the same numerical order as the squared dot products $(e_i \cdot u)^2$?

**Intuition.** The dot products measure how elongated the distribution is towards that orthant.

**Empirical support.** I have created $>10\;000$ random instances, with dimensions uniformly random between $3$ and $7$, the stretching factor uniformly random between $1.01$ to $10$, and random rotation. To guard against numerical inaccuracy, I searched for cases where some two orthant probabilities would be in the wrong order and separated by more than $0.003$. No such cases were found.

**Note.** The case $k=2$ is easy, since we have closed-form expressions for the quadrant probability. Whenever the correlation between $X_1$ and $X_2$ is positive, the positive-positive quadrant has $> 1/4$ probability.

**Note.** The case $k=3$ *might* be easy using some known closed-form expressions, and that would be already interesting (but a positive answer here would not solve the general case).

**Note.** In [Which orthant probabilities are the largest? (For a multivariate normal distribution)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356787/which-orthant-probabilities-are-the-largest-for-a-multivariate-normal-distribu) the distribution was assumed to have two distinct eigenvalues, but the larger eigenvalue could be multiple. A corresponding conjecture turned out to be false already in dimension $4$ when each eigenvalue was double (the distribution was "stretched uniformly in two directions" before rotation).

*Edit. The first version of the question asked about dot products instead of their squares. That version would not make much sense (the answer would be negative already in $k=2$).*

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\la\lambda\newcommand\ep\varepsilon\newcommand{\de}{\delta}\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}$The answer is negative, even for $k=3$.

A counterexample is as follows:
$$\lambda=2,\quad u=\frac{(4,-3,-3)}{\sqrt{34}},$$
$$e_1:=(1,1,1)/\sqrt3,\quad e_2:=(-1,1,1)/\sqrt3.$$
Then $e_1\cdot u>e_2\cdot u$, whereas $p_1=0.100\ldots<0.183\ldots=p_2$.

---

The OP has changed the question, replacing the comparisons of the values of $e_i\cdot u$ by the comparisons of the values of $(e_i\cdot u)^2$.

Then the answer becomes positive, at least for $k=3$.

Indeed, if $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are jointly Gaussian zero-mean random variables with correlation coefficients $\rho_{ij}=Corr(X_i,X_j)$, then, by the 3rd display from the bottom of p. 355 of [Plackett's paper],
\begin{equation*}
    P(X_1>0,X_2>0,X_3>0) \\ 
    =\frac1{4\pi}\,(2\pi-\cos^{-1}\rho_{12}-\cos^{-1}\rho_{23}-\cos^{-1}\rho_{31}). 
\end{equation*}

If $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is an eigenvector of the covariance matrix $\Si$ of the random vector $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $t:=\la>1$, with the other two eigenvalues each equal $1$, then
\begin{equation*}
    \Si=\frac1{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2} 
    \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_1^2 t+a_2^2+a_3^2 & a_1 a_2 (t-1) & a_1 a_3 (t-1) \\
 a_1 a_2 (t-1) & a_2^2 t+a_1^2+a_3^2 & a_2 a_3 (t-1) \\
 a_1 a_3 (t-1) & a_2 a_3 (t-1) & a_3^2 t+a_1^2+a_2^2 \\
\end{array}
\right). 
\end{equation*}

It follows that for any $\ep=(\ep_1,\ep_2,\ep_3)\in\{-1,1\}^3$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
p_{a,\ep}:=4\pi P(\ep_1 X_1>0,\ep_2 X_2>0,\ep_3 X_3>0)-2\pi \\
=-\cos ^{-1}R_{12}-\cos ^{-1}R_{23}-\cos ^{-1}R_{31},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    R_{ij}:=\frac{(t-1)a_i a_j \ep_i \ep_j }
    {\sqrt{\big((t-1)a_i^2+a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2\big) \big((t-1)a_j^2+a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2\big) }}. 
\end{equation*}

We want to show that for any $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in\R^2\setminus\{0\}$ and any $\de=(\de_1,\de_2,\de_3)$ and $\ep=(\ep_1,\ep_2,\ep_3)$ in $\{-1,1\}^3$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    (a\cdot\de)^2\le(a\cdot\ep)^2 \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
we have
\begin{equation*}
    p_{a,\de}\le p_{a,\ep}. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}

Note that $p_{a,\ep}$ is even in $a$ and in $\ep$ ($p_{-a,\ep}=p_{a,\ep}=p_{a,-\ep}$), and $(a\cdot\ep)^2$ is even in $a$ and in $\ep$ as well. Also, $p_{a,\ep}$ is permutation invariant: $p_{a,\ep}$ remains invariant if the indices of $a$ and $\ep$ are permuted by the same permutation. So, without loss of generality (wlog)
\begin{equation*}
    \de=(-1,1,1)\quad\text{and}\quad\ep=(1,1,1), 
\end{equation*}
and then conditions \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} can be rewritten as
\begin{equation*}
    a_1(a_2+a_3)\ge0\tag{1a}\label{1a}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    \sin^{-1}S_{12}+\sin^{-1}S_{13}\ge0, \tag{2a}\label{2a}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    S_{ij}:=S_{ij}(a):=\frac{(t-1)a_i a_j }
    {\sqrt{\big((t-1)a_i^2+a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2\big) \big((t-1)a_j^2+a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2\big) }}. 
\end{equation*}
Also, $a_1(a_2+a_3)$ and the $R_{ij}$'s are even in $a$, and the $S_{ij}$'s are homogeneous in $a$: $S_{ij}(ka)=S_{ij}(a)$ for any real $k\ne0$. Also, by continuity, wlog the inequality in \eqref{1a} is strict. So, wlog $a_1=1$ and $a_2+a_3>0$.

So, wlog $a_2=a$ and $a_3=b$ for some real $a$ and $b$ such that $a>0$ and $a+b>0$.

If $b\ge0$, then $S_{12}\ge0$ and $S_{13}\ge0$, so that \eqref{2a} is obvious.

If $b<0$, then $-a<b<0$ and hence $b^2<a^2$. Then ($S_{12}>0$ and)
\begin{equation*}
    r(t):=\frac{S_{13}^2}{S_{12}^2}=\frac{b^2 \left(a^2 t+b^2+1\right)}{a^2 \left(a^2+b^2 t+1\right)}, 
\end{equation*}
which is increasing from $r(1+)=\frac{b^2}{a^2}<1$ to $r(\infty-)=1$ as $t$ is increasing from $1$ to $\infty$, so that $|S_{13}|<S_{12}$ and \eqref{2a} follows. $\quad\Box$

Comment: You are right. Here both dot products are negative and $e_1 \cdot u$ has the smaller absolute value, hence is greater. I apologize; I meant to ask about the absolute values (or squares) of the dot products, which would make more sense here. Would you mind if I just edit the question to reflect what I had in mind? Alternatively, I can make a new question.

Comment: Thanks; since you have now already answered the k=3 case with squared dot products, I guess I can as well now change the question to use squared dot products as intended.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen : How did you compute the probabilities for $k=6,7$?

Comment: By calling Matlab's "mvncdf" from code similar to [my answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356787/which-orthant-probabilities-are-the-largest-for-a-multivariate-normal-distribu/439070#439070). From the documentation, mvncdf is doing quasi-Monte Carlo integration. Since I was searching for discrepancies greater than $0.003$, my negative findings are hardly conclusive of anything, but I could retry with smaller tolerance. (With $k=7$ we have 128 orthants so it is conceivable that any violations of the inequality in question might be numerically small.)